# Estimate size of differential backup alternatives

Tags: sql-server, database-backups

I found a method to estimate the size of a differential backup in [this](https://dougzuck.com/sql-differential-backup-size-prediction) article. The problem is that it requires the sysadmin role. Is it a good idea, as a poor-man's solution, to get the size of the backup by making a backup to the `'nul'` device and then checking the `backupset` view of the `msdb` database?

Answer (score 2):

There is a new method that's been introduced since this question was asked (and answered). The sys.dm_db_file_space_usage system view has a modified_extent_page_count column that will tell you how many pages have been modified since the last full backup. Summing that across all of the files in the database should give you a good estimate of the size of the differential backup.

The OP was concerned about the other method needing sysadmin. This also requires elevated permissions (`VIEW SERVER STATE`), but doesn't need sysadmin.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a very small backup, performing a differential backup up to 'nul' would probably be fine because it would be quick and should give you a reliable way to predict the size of the actual differential backup to disk.  However, for a large differential it will take time to complete the 'nul' backup, and depending on how much activity the server gets and how much time you have, you might not want this.

I assume if you have a need to predict/estimate the size of the differential, then you are probably working with large databases.  However, unfortunately I don't think you will find a better/different way than the method outlined in the article you linked above (https://dougzuck.com/sql-differential-backup-size-prediction) to get a real estimate of a SQL differential backup size.